# Best multicluster configuration for mTLS between applications

Tags: istio, mtls

I want to configure 2 Kubernetes clusters with Istio multicluster, and I'm thinking of these 2 options:

1. Replicated control planes (https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/multicluster/gateways/)
2. Shared control plane (single-network) (https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/multicluster/shared-vpn/)

I would prefer to use replicated control planes for availability reasons, but the following question comes to my mind: How does mTLS between application work in this case?

If 2 applications of the same cluster talk to each other, and mTLS is enabled I can create an AuthorizationPolicy like this one:

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "AuthorizationPolicy"
metadata:
  name: "allow-app-a"
  namespace: app-b
spec:
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        principals: ["cluster.local/ns/app-a/sa/default"]
    to:
    - operation:
        methods: ["GET"]
```

The `app-a` is identified by its principal provided by mTLS.

If we have are deploying the multicluster with replicated control planes (version 1) we would have something like this:

[multicluster with replicated control planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MSZP.png)

How are applications in different cluster (cluster.global) identified? All traffic is going through the gateway, my guess is that it will never read the principal from the original caller, it will read the principal from the gateway. Is this right?

Is there anyway to solve this?
Can I get replicated control planes but with no gateways deployments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should chose multicluster model based on Your requirements, not the other way around. According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/ops/deployment/deployment-models/#multiple-clusters):

Shared control plane (single-network) model is the simplest and is mainly used as one mesh spanning over multiple clusters.

---

As for replicated control planes model, it is mainly used for availability and redundancy fail-over where You have sort of replicas of Your cluster and mesh in multiple regions. This way You can achieve to have same configuration and policy on both clusters. It can also be used in an advanced way like in [here](https://istio.io/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/).

Istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/multicluster/gateways/#summary) summarizes replicated control plane with the following:

> Using Istio gateways, a common root CA, and service entries, you can configure a single Istio service mesh across multiple Kubernetes clusters. Once configured this way, traffic can be transparently routed to remote clusters without any application involvement. Although this approach requires a certain amount of manual configuration for remote service access, the service entry creation process could be automated.

As for cross cluster communication and mTLS according to [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/multicluster/gateways/):

> Cross cluster communication requires mutual TLS connection between services. To enable mutual TLS communication across clusters, each cluster’s Citadel will be configured with intermediate CA credentials generated by a shared root CA. For illustration purposes, you use a sample root CA certificate available in the Istio installation under the samples/certs directory.

---

> How are applications in different cluster (cluster.global) identified?

By the `host` name that the applications are introduced to service mesh registry. You can use `ServiceEntry` objects to configure global visibility of services. You can find an example [here](https://istio.io/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/).

One of [multi-mesh deployment feature](https://istio.io/blog/2019/isolated-clusters/#features-of-multi-mesh-deployments) is:

> None of the services in a mesh are exposed by default, the mesh owners must explicitly specify which services are exposed.

---

> All traffic is going through the gateway, my guess is that it will never read the principal from the original caller, it will read the principal from the gateway. Is this right?

This depends on Your `Gateway` configuration. You can have [Ingress Gateway without TLS Termination](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/) which instructs the gateway to pass the ingress traffic AS IS, without terminating TLS. This way the source address will be preserved.

> Can I get replicated control planes but with no gateways deployments?

No, for multicluster model with replicated control planes each cluster still has its `Gateways` that are used for routing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Everything very clear, thanks Piotr.
I guess my best choice would be replicated control plane and configure the Ingress Gateway without TLS termination.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept the answer, it means a lot to me.